# Elliptic curves whose $2,3,5$-parts of Sha are large

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve, and $\text{Sha}(E)$ its Shafarevich-Tate group which measures the failure of the local-to-global principle for the curve. It is conjectured that $\text{Sha}(E)$ is a finite group for every elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$, and it is known that for any prime $p$ the $p^\infty$-part of $\text{Sha}(E)$ is finite.

My question is: does there exist an infinite family of elliptic curves $E$ such that $\text{Sha}_2(E), \text{Sha}_3(E), \text{Sha}_5(E)$ all tend to infinity in size?

A similar, but perhaps more accessible question, is to ask the same thing of the Selmer groups instead.

Comment: It is only known in general that the $n$ torsion part is finite. The primary parts are known to be finite only if the analytic rank is zero or one (over the rationales).

Comment: I ave no troubles believing that such a family exists. But I wonder what you want to do with it?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich I want to think about the problem of bounding the rank uniformly in large families, and one approach is to think about families where at least one of 2, 3, or 5 Selmer is bounded in size. These particular primes arose because we have a good understanding of the co-regular spaces parametrizing the Selmer elements.

Comment: What do you mean by "family"? And "large family"?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich the use of the word "family" is admittedly ambiguous. I am simply looking for a sequence $\{E_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of elliptic curves with the property that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \min \{|\text{Sel}_2(E_n)|, |\text{Sel}_3(E_n)|, |\text{Sel}_5(E_n)|\} = \infty$. "Large" family refers to a family which has positive density.

Comment: Delaunay heuristics will say that the proportion of elliptic curves with sha of size $(2\cdot 3\cdot 5)^{2k}$ is positive for all $k$, right? So you expect it to exist in that sense, no? But explicitly constructing one seems hard to me. A cyclic isogeny of degree 30 might have helped but they don't exist over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Possibly related, while I wouldn't gamble on it: https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.08088